# *ngIf-else not showing else results

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, angular6

I have no idea why this isn't working and I'm stuck. Can anyone spot what is wrong with my code?

Im trying to show a Not found message when there are no tickets to show. I tried getting the result via tickets array lenght, but it always shows that the length is 0.

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tickets; else elseTemplate">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
        <div class="card">
          <h5 class="card-header"><span class="fa fa-ticket"></span> Pileti nr. {{ticket._id}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
  <div><h1>Ticket not found.</h1></div>
</ng-template>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketService } from '../../ticket.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reg-ticket-list',
  templateUrl: './reg-ticket-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reg-ticket-list.component.css']
})
export class RegTicketListComponent implements OnInit {

  reg: string;

  public tickets = [];

  constructor(private ticketService: TicketService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private _location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.reg = this.route.snapshot.params.reg;
      this.ticketService.getTicketsByReg(this.reg)
          .subscribe(data => this.tickets = data);
    }

    dateFormat(date) {
      moment.locale('et');
      return moment(date).format("Do MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss")
    }

    goBack() {
      this._location.back();
    }

}
```

Comment: `*ngIf="tickets; ` will only check that it's not null. Try `*ngIf="tickets && ticket.length; `

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Got it working now, thank you! If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `*ngIf="tickets;`, this will only check if `tickets` is falsey, and an empty array is not falsey (although `null` is).

Instead, you can use `*ngIf="tickets && ticket.length;` which will also check that there's the length is not 0